# Strategy to Improve Awareness of Site and Attract More users

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, beta

We need to try to increase awareness of this site and attract more users.

What are the strategies we can follow?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it's just a matter of time. All beta sites start slow and in time people will find this site and the community will grow. Most people find this site via Google so if you want to do something the best is to:

- Create good and practical question with terms that interested people would use in searches. (BTW, the most valued questions often are those that people can related to and wanted to ask for themselves)
- Answer those questions with high-quality answers.

Besides that you can promote [the best questions](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) we've got so far by posting them on relevant other sites.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to share your questions and answers on Facebook; that's the best way to attract people, and get medals to boot - you get the "Announcer" badge if 25 people click on a link you shared.

Comment: Only if you share the link you get from clicking the "share" link below a post will you get points for the badge. It's the one that's got your unique identifier.